# Displaying toast on no data coming form webservice crashes app in android

Tags: android, web-services, toast

all. I am working with a dummy application where I am displaying data coming from wheather webservice http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=CityName .Everything is working fine but issue I am facing is that when I display Toast on no data coming from server or when internet may not be availabe on device my app crashes in emulator diplaying.

```
"Unfortunately wheather app stopped working "
```

This problem only arises when there is no internet on the device. the line creating issues for me when I disconnect Internet is like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Not able to connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

if I comment this line my app works fine. My all code on this file is like this:

```
package com.mubu.wheathertoday.wheathertoday;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText etCity;
    Button btnShow;
    ProgressDialog pbar;
    String JsonString;
    TextView tvr;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         etCity=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCity);
        btnShow=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShow);


        btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AsyncGetData gd=new AsyncGetData();
                gd.execute();
            }

        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private  class AsyncGetData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
  try {
      ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
      String url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+etCity.getText().toString().trim();
    JsonString = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST);
      if (JsonString != null) {
         Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WheatherActivity.class);
          try{
          i.putExtra("jsn",JsonString);
         i.putExtra("city",etCity.getText().toString());
           startActivity(i);
          }catch (Exception e){


      }
      }
      else
      {
    try{

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Not able to connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


 // if I disconnect Internet this line gets executed and my app crashes
            }catch (Exception e){


}
      }

      }
  catch (Exception e){etCity.setText(e.getMessage());}
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

              pbar=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pbar.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pbar.setCancelable(false);
            pbar.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
           if(pbar.isShowing() )
                pbar.dismiss();


        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When you get the crash, in you Android Console (LogCat) you should see an exception trace. Please copy it here (only first two / three lines, not complete exception trace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to update your user interface from `doInBackground`. `doInBackground`runs in a background thread, not in the main (also called UI Thread).

As you can read in the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) documentation (emphasis mine):

> onPreExecute(), **invoked on the UI thread** before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
>
> doInBackground(Params...), **invoked on the background thread** immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used to perform background computation that can take a long time. The parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be passed back to the last step. This step can also use publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress. These values are published on the UI thread, in the onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
>
> onProgressUpdate(Progress...), **invoked on the UI thread** after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the user interface while the background computation is still executing. For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field.
>
> onPostExecute(Result), **invoked on the UI thread** after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

So you need to do that Toast elsewhere. For example you can define an Interface within your Asynctask with a callback method:

```
public interface MyTaskInterface {
    public void onNetworkError();
}
```

You define a listener inside your AsyncTask:

```
private MyTaskInterface listener;
```

Add getters & setters for listener and you can write:

```
if (listener != null) {
    listener.onNetworkError();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should not make Toast in "doInbackground". Because it is not a UI thread.

Try to do it in "onPostExecute".

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to show Toast in `doInBackground`. Any UI related functionalities should not be called from this method because this is background thread. You have to show toast from `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you have **internet permission.**
if it is correct then as per year code you are toasting a message on Background thread.
While UI work is not allowed in background.
So Either you toast message onPost() method or you can apply below code.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Not able to connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

So `**runOnUiThread**` allow us to do a UI operation from background thread. I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is to show toast in background that you cannot do that if you want to show toast you have to write that piece of code in onPostExecute

what you can do is you have to create a boolean variable in that asyntask calss suppose named as _Is_Responce_Received=false;

and in

```
if (JsonString != null) {
 _Is_Responce_Received=true;
  // rest of your code

 }
```

and in your post execute

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

 if(!_Is_Responce_Received){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Not able to connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
       if(pbar.isShowing() )
            pbar.dismiss();


    }
```